# How to make a List of interfaces to perform a action

Tags: c#, builder-pattern

I know the question can be answered by saying `foreach(var item in items){item.doSomething()};` but what i'm after is slightly different. Here is the interface.

**ManagableClass .cs**

```
public interface ManagableClass : System.IDisposable
{
    void Initialize();
}
```

and below is how I would like to see my code look like

**MainManagerClass.cs**

```
public class MainManagerClass: ManagableClass
{
    private List<ManagableClass> minions;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        TellMinionsTo(Initialize);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        TellMinionsTo(Dispose);
    }

    private void TellMinionsTo(Action doSomething)
    {
        foreach (ManagableClass minion in minions)
        {
            minion.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that this code that is here will not work, but it seems like this *should* be doable in C#. Anyone know if this can be done? If not it's not like it's the end of the world, I'll just do a `foreach` in each method.

Comment: is the list of minions going to be the same throughout each interface? i.e., should all derived classes be working w. the same list?

Comment: The list of minions will is of type `ManagableClass`, so they will have the 2 methods i'm after (Initialize, and Dispose)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you pass a delegate to a method of a certain instance (yourself), while what you want is to invoke a certain method on all minions.

You can use lambda expressions, something like

```
public void Dispose()
{
   TellMinionsTo(minion=>minion.Dispose());
}    


private void TellMinionsTo(Action<ManagableClass> doSomething)
{
    foreach (ManagableClass minion in minions)
    {
         doSomething(minion);
    }
}
```

I don't like using List's method directly. Tomorrow you'll have to work via an interface and your IList may not have to be a List at all.

Comment: I decided to switch to your answer, because although Gretro indirectly answered my question (I looked at intellisense with the ForEach method, and suprise it mataches your answer). But I like how the code reads as opposed to `minions.ForEach(i=>i.Dispose());`

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a [Composite pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx). This pattern will allow you to have a class that will implement the correct method and differ it to a list of items. However, in your case, you need to modify your interface to implement the `DoSomething()` method. So, instead, this should look like this.

```
public interface ISomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class SomethingManager : ISomething 
{
    private List<ISomething> _items = new List<ISomething>();

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _items.ForEach(i => i.DoSomething());
    }
}
```

Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Although it isn't exactly what I was after, I didn't know List had an extension method of ForEach. Indirectly You answered my question. Somehow I thought I was implementing the Builder Design pattern (same website), thank you for correcting me on that.